# Problem importing a library I created for Angular from NPM

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, frontend, lib

I am trying to make a generic component that uses primeng inside, I would like to publish it on npm to make it available, I tried but once I import it with "npm install" it gives me error:

```
Cannot read property 'ecmp' of undefined in angular
```

Instead if I try to import via .tar file or dist folder it works, the project can be viewed here: https://github.com/hetsrl/my-prime-table

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant config-files (such as angular.json, package.json) so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @kellermat the configuration files you ask for can be found inside the github repository linked above.

Comment: It was just a recommendation, because it would increase the probability that someone answers your question. When the question is too broad, in the sense of "please check my github-repo" the probability that someone will help you tends to zero. Btw: I cannot help you since I'm not really experienced with npm-libraries.